# Window Security pop up while downloading word document from Wordpress Website

Tags: php, wordpress, internet-explorer-9, download

I have a wordpress website which provides a download link to a word document. When user clicks on the download link in IE-9 a windows security pop up is shown to user. It works fine in all the other browsers.

I have done some search and found that it is due to some security settings in IE-9. 
Is there any way I can overcome this setting because all the users will mostly have this security setting?

**UPDATE** This problem comes only if user selects open. If user selects save or save as option from the Save dialog it works fine.

This is the security pop up

[image]

Comment: What "security window" exactly? What does it say? Also, if it's *security* related, it'd be kind of nonsensical if there was an easy way to suppress it, no?

Comment: Checked and found this solution http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/windows-security-popup-asking-me-to-enter-my-login/530deb46-0962-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5 but it is client side solution. I am looking for some server side solution to this.

Comment: This problem exists only for word files. So I think there must be some setting for word rather than IE9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this. The Internet explorer does not handle word files properly so I implemented a PHP script for explicitly downloading the files and it worked

Answer (score 2):

This answer provides a server side fix, if you are running IIS.  The issue is that the security popup appears when a user tries to open a Word document through IE9, rather than straight download it.

> ...We have the setup on IIS7 and elected to disable 'WebDAV' (All updates are done by uploading the files anyway). To do this open IIS7, select either the server or the site and click the "Request Filtering". Action - Deny Verb... and enter PROPFIND. Create another for OPTIONS. I found that the server did not need a reboot and it was fixed straight away. Hope that is useful to someone. -Stuart

Credit goes to Stuart from the Moodle forums:  https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=143111